# Does Stack Overflow aspire to a standard of gender-neutral language?

Tags: discussion, languages

Does SO have any standards on the idea of gendered language? I believe that it is unwise to allow male pronouns to rule the day. Let me give you an example. I just posted a  [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223404/229177) where the original title was "Why did a user delete their own question?", wherein I intentionally used the vague (but technically/historically incorrect) pronoun "their" since I had no idea what the gender of the user was, and it doesn't matter for anyone's purpose anyway.

Almost immediately, an edit was suggested to replace "their" with "his". I thought that was inappropriate. I decided to use "his/her" since that seemed a little more inclusive, but that still isn't fully inclusive. Fully inclusive language might be my own personal goal –  but how much is that considered a general goal here? I'm not necessarily suggesting editing every question to make them wonderfully gender-neutral, but it would be nice if I knew what the preferred option was. Or should I just take charge and make my own call where I can?

Comment: Okay, come on, why the downvote?

Comment: Regardless of gender politics, that was a horrible suggested edit. You should have rejected it instead of improved it; you gave Revious rep and taught him to do that more.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would "his/her" be "not fully inclusive"? I may be missing something, but what other case isn't covered by that pattern?

Comment: @Wooble, okay, fair enough, mistake was made, lesson learned. The reason I accepted it was because I thought the respacing of my question was fair, and I assumed there was some room for discussion of gendered language preferences, which led me to this question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: are you aware that Facebook just literally added 50 choices for gender?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, um, some people don't like to be called "his" or "her".

Comment: @Wooble, I'm afraid I don't know much about that Facebook thing you're speaking about :) More seriously, how would "his/her" not be appropriate in all cases? There is no other gender possessive as far as I know (except "its", and I don't think it should apply to people).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender.

Comment: @patrickvacek, okay, are you saying there are intersex people that like neither "his" nor "her"? What are we supposed to do, create another possessive?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, that is a common suggestion. I am trying to figure out what the standard is here. There is a body of literature and discussion on this topic outside of SO, so I was curious if there were relevant opinions here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222024/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral

Comment: Like it or not, "their" is becoming (or even has become) an acceptable gender-neutral singular possessive pronoun.

Comment: @AlE. "Their" is just fine with me! That's why I used it originally! I think language should grow as needs evolve, so I find the conventional limitations of it unnecessary and thus I repurpose it for gender-neutral use. But I know that bothers some people.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you might enjoy [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Gender](http://www.cscyphers.com/blog/2012/06/28/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-gender/), part of [a loose 'series'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="falsehoods+programmers+believe+about+*") that began with [...Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @AlE. Singular they has been around for longer than people think. The [1300s by some estimates](http://www.crossmyt.com/hc/linghebr/austheir.html#X1x)

Comment: 7 downvotes on my question and 12 upvotes on the first answer! Wow, people clearly don't like when gender gets in the way of their complacency! How is this not a valid question about how to handle edits and language in general?

Comment: @patrickvacek I'm really not sure. I mean this is a duplicate but duplicates usually don't get this poor a reception. It seems like a perfectly fair request for advice on what you should do

Comment: Apparently, programmers like binary in everything, include their genders.

Comment: @AlE. that's the lesson I've learned here as well. How depressing. I've never even seen so many downvotes before. Getting marked as a duplicate is annoying, but I sort of get it. Since my question was clearly slanted or biased towards one approach, and consequently greatly downvoted, that tells you a lot about what people think about the opinion I implicitly expressed.

Comment: @patrickvacek The wierd thing is you've expressed more or less the same opinion as the duplicate; which was very well recieved; as it should be since using "he" to mean "someone" is horrible

Comment: @RichardTingle, I actually think my question was a little more clearly opinionated than the other. *However*, the answers to that one were even more explicitly strongly slanted (in the same direction as my question, I'd say), which makes it very, very odd indeed.

Comment: At the end of the day, StackOverflow is a subset of society that is focused on technology questions. We have a modest goal here, that is to help people code. We can't distract ourselves

Comment: @Adel, so first (on another post) you recommend speaking up, and then in the end you chastise me for doing it? I agree with your first two sentences, but not the third. Inclusion is not a distraction; it is important the very mission of SO as stated in your second sentence ("help people code"). Why not try to help the most people instead of scaring a subset away?

Comment: Now it's -10 (14 downvotes total) with a vote to delete as well. Seriously, I asked a fair question and even received a couple fair answers. Why all the presumptive disapproval?

Comment: @patrickvacek At least +4*5+14*(-2)=-8, so not too much rep lost

Comment: @RichardTingle, yeah, I know. I'm not complaining about losing reputation, just that the question is being treated as useless or worse. Oddly, it just dropped to -12 in the past few minutes. At this point I feel like I'm being targeted. (Nothing else I've posted is being treated in that way, though, so at least it isn't serial.)

Comment: @patrickvacek I've been talking to a few people in chat and the prevaling view is that people are simply tired of this topic coming up; It does come up relatively regularly. Whether this is fair to you is questionable but it is at least a reason

Comment: @RichardTingle, thanks for the input. However, it's almost like it might keep coming up because there is a problem or flaw in the system. Also, I can't help but feel that the treatment I received indicates that discussion of gender language/expression/etc. is not welcome here.

Comment: For the sake of assuming the best in everyone, the user originally referred to using "their" does appear to be male (if you follow the links in their profile).  It's possible that the editor thought they were helping by trying to determine the user's gender and then adding that information to your question to make it read more smoothly.

Comment: Also, that user isn't a native speaker. They may not have understood the meaning of "their" in tne first place. (Of course, in that case they shouldn't be editing at all).

Comment: Some of the downvotes may have come from the perception that you're suggesting imposing a system of "correct speech" on a community that (except for swearing) has very few fixed rules in how to write a contribution. I was initially under the same impression. But that's of course not what your post is about. I don't think the downvotes on this post are justified, but the duplicate question and the upvotes it received is indication enough that discussion about this is not fundamentally unwanted in our community.

Comment: Well, here's an anecdote: My native language has just one gender-neutral pronoun for him/her, and I've preferred singular "they" for as long as I've known it's valid English. I just get all confused if I have to know or specify the gender when it's unknown or irrelevant.

Comment: This isn't an 'exact duplicate' at all. At least at the time that I'm writing this comment, this question is about StackOverflow policy, while the other question is about people's perceptions about the community. They're different things.

Comment: @hyde What language is that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't have nor need a standard for the correct way to spell the gender-indeterminate singular pronoun, anymore than it needs a standard for how "color" or "colour" is spelled (outside of code), or any other point of grammar.

The usage of the original poster should just be retained; edits to change them like the one you mention should be rejected as Too Minor or Invalid.

What pronouns you choose to use in your own submissions are up to you; there's no wider Style Guide for anything else in posts, either.

Comment: I appreciate that you actually answered my question and offered some substantive advice. While the wider discussion was fun, I clearly upset many people. Thank you for at least telling me what is "normal" around here, even if I disagree somewhat with how that plays out.

Comment: I love how the two-character edit to this answer was not rejected as 'Too minor'. 

Answer (score 5):

[All edits should be substantive edits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/).

Answer (score -3):

The male pronoun is the English language standard, and has been for many hundreds of years.  It's not an issue unless you make it one, it's the norm.  Having said that there is really no need to edit pronouns for "gender" (in general), but there certainly may be for "number", since "their" is a plural.  I do lots of edits for plurality issues, since it's just bad grammar, and "catches" you when you read the post, i.e. not smooth.

Comment: Completely agree - I hate bad grammar :-P

Comment: @Doorknob, since there is no standard of the English language, how do you define "bad grammar"? For example, I thought your comment was a joke at first, since I had been taught to say "poor grammar" when I was in school.

Comment: Actually 'singular they' has been around for longer than people think. The [1300s by some estimates](http://www.crossmyt.com/hc/linghebr/austheir.html#X1x). Regardless using he or she when you mean 'someone' jars horribly. If people don't like 'singular they' they should use "a person", "someone", "the OP" etc

Comment: I also forgot to mention: beyond the issue of there not being a standard of the English language, I don't like the idea that "[i]t's not an issue unless you make it one." Talk about victim-blaming! Should I apologize that some people don't fit in some arbitrary restricted notion of a gender binary?

Comment: @patrickvacek, it's not arbitrary, it's a language.  I'm learning Koine Greek right now, and you wouldn't believe how much more gender can play into a language.  I also took a lot of French in the past and gender was a huge issue.  English is actually very loose in this regard.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, but it is arbitrary! What does it matter? I know many languages use gender even more. I speak German and am well acquainted with the concept. However, the issue I'm concerned with here is how *people* are gendered in language. It's almost a cultural issue. Actually, I think German may be even more progressive than English in this regard.

Comment: @LanceRoberts French, German etc however uses the word "gender" to mean two completely different things "biological gender" and "check digit" (girl is neuter for instance). Thankfully we don't have that issue and can focus soley on what is logical

Comment: @patrickvacek, language conventions came about for practical reasons over long periods of time.  Just because we can't trace all the reasons, doesn't make it arbitrary.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Language genders are theorised to be a random "check digit"; that if you can only half hear something an extra 0,1,2 check digit (male, female, neuter) can avoid confusion

Comment: @RichardTingle, I agree that that seems to be the main function, though I'm sure nobody designed it to be that way.  Regardless, gender does matter for grammar.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I'm sure its more of a "language evolution" rather than actively chosen. However; grammer is not a static thing, when it ceases to be useful it should be changed: as it was in the 1300s to correct this issue

Comment: @RichardTingle, yes, languages changed, but obviously English hasn't when it comes to using male pronouns to refer to any unknown gender individual/group.  There is a progressive element that is intentionally trying to change the language to advance their ideology, but no natural language evolution going on here (like it did when we lost "thee"/"thou" and just went to "you").

Comment: @LanceRoberts, why does gender matter? I also disagree that mere existence of history makes something not arbitrary. In fact, I think we are disagreeing about what it means to be arbitrary: my point is that precisely because gender is a concept that serves little to no practical function and it has vague historical origin, it is arbitrary to the utmost degree. Simply put, gender doesn't matter, so why do we care so much about keeping its conventions?

Comment: @LanceRoberts What ideology is that? That people come in 2 genders? This is what I have never understood about the defence of "he". Why do you think "he" makes sense even when the person may be female (v.s any other construct, be that "a person", "he/she", "s(he)", [context dependant term such as "a soldier"]

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, LOL, language is politics. I was just waiting someone to make that move.

Comment: @patrickvacek, well I disagree, since I think gender does matter, and so does my girlfriend.  It's a fact of life, not something that should just be hidden away and never mentioned.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian As a question of how SE standards this question is on topic IMO

Comment: @RichardTingle, using the male pronoun is just a convenience we have in our language.  We have to use something, and that is how our language has chosen to handle this situation.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, so kind of you to speak for your girlfriend. I also don't believe gender should be "hidden away and never mentioned" -- I asked this ridiculous question in the first place! I also disagree with using male pronouns out of convenience... I happen to find that unfair. When you say "our language has chosen...", who is "our language"? That's an odd personification.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I get that we're not going to come to an agreement, saying "he" has always seemed wrong to me (not morally; actually, as in it is an incorrect statement) whereas we have several less incorrect alternative. It is also makes it very difficult when you want to say "he" when "he" actually is male. This is only going to get worse as more and more maleness cannot be assumed: "he'll be arrested if he goes in there!", "why?!", "its the womens bathroom", "so?", "He's a man", "O, I see! Why didn't you say". It'll happen if 'he' isn't reserved for its true meaning, not soon, but it will

Comment: @patrickvacek, you can fight against what has been established (and many people do), but I was only pointing out that it was established.  Personally, I like the fact that we have a simple, easy way to do pronouns.

Answer (score -4):

People are correcting 'their' to 'his' or 'her' when they think it's inappropriate. They were learned in school that 'their' is inappropriate when referring single person, so if they read from context, that the asker is a single person, they correct such grammatical error.

I haven't seen any English grammar book stating that you can use 'their' referring to single person. Maybe I'm wrong because newer grammar books contains other rules, but in those I've learned English from (usually signed by Oxford Press, AFAIK) it was not the case.

In that particular case some user has done such a minor suggested edit, either in good faith or for rep hunting, correcting what he thought to be grammar error to what he thought is the only acceptable correct English. It hasn't change anything substantial in the post, as well as the further revisions trying to "reverse" the "damage". In my opinion there's no sense to spilt milk over it.

Comment: the [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) dates back to at least Shakespeare's time.  And then from our own English.SE [Is the “one's” and “their” used correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103793/is-the-ones-and-their-used-correctly)

Comment: @MichaelIT I'm referring to the fact that I haven't met such usage in English grammar books that were used for teaching English internationally. This is what defines the standard according to which people are fixing grammar errors. After all, we speak English better or worse, but for most of us it's the language we've learned from books.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ, I am sympathetic to that, I promise, but as has been said before, "there's more to life than books!". Sadly, my knowledge of German was arguably rather weak until I went to Austria and heard how it was spoken there. Language grammar books are often rather conservative and don't always keep up well with new and growing trends.

Comment: Because I once took an English Composition course with peer review and an ESL student who told me it's never acceptable to begin a sentence with the word "because", I don't put a lot of stock in English grammar books written for teaching English to non-native speakers.

Comment: @patrickvacek but grammar is about the books, at the end. If you make any test, like FCE, I wish you success if you want to proove you haven't make a mistake, giving various blog resources as referrence.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ If you have time, I would suggest given a listen to [this](http://www.waywordradio.org/third-person-singular/) radio program about the history and use of English - this particular call in was about 'their' vs 'his' or 'hers'.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ, I'm sorry, I couldn't disagree more. "Grammar is about the books"? What books!? There is no standard of the English language, unlike, for example, German. Grammar is about communication and making yourself understood. I want to make sure no one is shut out by my choice of words.

Comment: @patrickvacek very interesting theory. So how, in your opinion, are tests like FCE checked?

Comment: They're checked against someone's idea of what is correct, but there are plenty of disagreements and differences in what those ideas are. Certainly you are familiar with the differences between British English and American English? Or maybe even the idea of dialects within those countries?

Comment: Some style guides are OK with a singular "they" and "their". *I* don't like it much and don't like to write it, but I don't "correct" it when other do either. Likewise, I will thank you not to mangle my correct usage of "his or her"; I'd even prefer neologisms like "hir".

Comment: Hooray, someone finally mentioned "hir" and it wasn't even derisive! (Thanks @dmckee!)